# Bootstrap Issue With Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've an issue with Bootstrap Modal when trying to show/hide it using code. When we enter text with more than 3 characters and press Enter once, the modal shows and then disappears as intended. However, if we keep on pressing Enter key, the screen turns black.

I've seen other posts with this issue and all of them suggest to use `data-keyboard="false"`, but this doesn't work in my case. Could somebody please help?

**UPDATE**

The code snippet is now updated with working solution posted in answer.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#txtSearch").keydown(function(event){
    if($.trim($(this).val()) != "" && $(this).val().length > 3 && event.which == 13 ){
      showLoading();

      //Some Code
      hideLoading();
  }
  });
  
});

function showLoading(){
  if(!$('.modal-backdrop').is(':visible')){
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
  }
}

function hideLoading(){
  $("#myModal").modal("hide");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtSearch" />
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<h1 style="color:white">Loading...</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a common problem with state management; you're triggering `.modal("show");` multiple times, so you'll need to set and keep track of a variable that prevents this; for example `var isLoading = false;`, which if set to `true`, will prevent the execution of `showLoading()`.

Comment: @TimLewis - I've added a variable as suggested, but the problem persists. Please see my updated code.

Comment: It might all be happening too quick in this case; there's no time between opening and closing, so you might need to add handlers for `.on("shown.bs.modal")` and `.on("hidden.bs.modal")` to properly handle this.

Comment: @TimLewis - Updated code, but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead to use the global variable **isLoading** I suggest to test if the **modal-backdrop** is visible before opening the modal:

```
if (!$('.modal-backdrop').is(':visible')) {
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
    console.log('show');
}
```

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtSearch").keydown(function (event) {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) != "" && $(this).val().length > 3 && event.which == 13) {
            showLoading();
            setTimeout(function() {
                hideLoading();
            }, 1000);
            //Some Code
            //hideLoading();
        }
    });

});

function showLoading() {
    if (!$('.modal-backdrop').is(':visible')) {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        console.log('show');
    }
}

function hideLoading() {
    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
    console.log('hide');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<input id="txtSearch"/>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <h1 style="color:white">Loading...</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and I've updated it in my code snippet as well. :)

Comment: Would this when there is already another modal showing?

Comment: @jonCianci I assume only a modal at a time